# Typescript remove property restructure array

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

Convert array to array below in typescript.

Before:

`

```
[
   {propety: 332}, 
   {propety: 325}, 
   {propety: 125}
]
```

`

After:

`

```
[
   {332, 325, 125}
]
```

`

Comment: `[{332, 325, 125}]` is invalid JavaScript/TypeScript.  Please [edit] this to remove any typos, provide a [mre], and to clearly ask a question as described in [ask].  Are you just asking how to map an array of objects to an array of one of its properties, like `arr.map(x => x.propety)`?  Have you tried anything yourself?  Have you searched for existing questions on the topic?

Comment: Yes but nothing to this level.  Maybe not using the correct search term not even the brackets are needed. just remove the obj property and convert to one array not a list.

Comment: map that was all and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Mapping an array of objects to an array of one of its properties using `arr.map(x => x.property)` worked.